# MySQL select more data in 1 result row of a query

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a table - `friends` which has 2 columns, both are `users` table `id`'s.

I have a table - `users` which has `id` and `username`.

I need a query that will return `username1`, `username2` from the friends table, instead of `id`'s.

I tried joining both tables, but it returns 2 result rows instead of one, which is not what I want.

I tried looking into multi select queries, but I didn't find anything particularly useful, is it possible to do that?

Comment: please show the structure of your table more clearly, we can not understand your schema and what you want

Comment: You mean generating username with id at end? Its not clear.

Comment: Table: user; int:id, text:username;
Table: friends; int:id, int:id;

Comment: I want to get to get two(2) usernames instead of two(2) id's from the friends table. These usernames can be looked up from the users table using the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left join the `users` table twice, once for each user:

```
SELECT 
    u1.username username1, 
    u2.username username2
FROM friends f
LEFT JOIN users u1
    ON f.first_id = u1.id
LEFT JOIN users u2
    ON f.second_id = u2.id
```

Where `first_id` and `second_id` are the id columns in your `friends` table.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/448ebe/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with 2 inner joins:

```
SELECT
    User1.Name user1_name,
    User2.Name user2_name
FROM
    friends
    INNER JOIN users User1 ON friends.User1_ID = User1.ID
    INNER JOIN users User2 ON friends.User2_ID = User2.ID
```